# How to create an input form for two related models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have models Movie and MovieDescription therefore I want to create an input form for these two models. I want the input to take place from one joint form, where there will be fields: title, directed_by, genre, year, rate, synopsis.

```py
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Title')
    directed_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Directed by')
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Genre')
    year = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Year')

class MovieDescription(models.Model):
    movie = models.OneToOneField('Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    synopsis = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Synopsis')
    rate = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Rate')
```

I have a problem with finding the most suitable django2.2 tool for this.

Comment: You have to use formsets to display both forms.

Comment: @Essex no you don't, a format wouldn't be appropriate here at all.

Comment: @Helen there's no "tool" for this, you can just use two forms.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why ? Formsets are used to display nested forms no ?

Comment: No, formsets are used to display multiple forms for the same model.

Comment: Ok thank you @DanielRoseman !